# Need help identifying these 7 lego pieces!

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I need help identifying these 7 pieces. Please assist!

What I tried so far is logically trying to figure out their categories, but unfortunately I couldn't find them, or there were hundreds/thousands of matches. If anyone knows, I'd appreciate a share. :)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

1. [Minifigure, Footgear Roller Skate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11253&idColor=11#T=C&C=11https://)
2. [Leg Skeleton](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=3282#T=C)
3. a scarf to be worn around the neck for minifigs, I can't remember the name
4. No idea
5. [Minifigure, Footgear Ice Skate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93555&name=Minifigure,%20Footgear%20Ice%20Skate&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=C)
6. [Carrot Top / Twig](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=994#T=C)
7. [Technic, Link Tread](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3873&name=Technic,%20Link%20Tread&category=%5BTechnic,%20Link%5D#T=C)

Answer (score 10):

**03** - [*Part #15619 Minifigure, Bandana Ninja.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15619&name=Minifigure,%20Bandana%20Ninja&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

**04** - [*Part #95747 Minifigure, Headgear Head Top, SW Zabrak Horns.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=95747&name=Minifigure,%20Headgear%20Head%20Top,%20SW%20Zabrak%20Horns&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Headgear%5D#T=S&C=150&O=%7B%22color%22:150,%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

[image]